# How to set a default ssh user for all hosts in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

Ansible version 2.1

I have an inventory file `hosts`

```
[nodes]
host1
host2
...
```

And a simple playbook `site.yml`

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - include: tasks/main.yml
```

If I just start the play,

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yml -vvvv
```

I get this error for all hosts,

```
ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
fatal: [host1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.", "unreachable": true}
...
```

However, reading [Ansible Inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters) doc, I added `ansible_user` to the `hosts` file,

```
[nodes]
host1    ansible_user=root
host2    ansible_user=root
...
```

This solves the `SSH CONNECTION UNREACHABLE` error. However, do I have to add `ansible_user=root` next to all the hosts? Or is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check the example/default `ansible.cfg` file, and you'll find this under `[defaults]`:

```
# default user to use for playbooks if user is not specified
# (/usr/bin/ansible will use current user as default)
#remote_user = root
```

**Uncomment `remote_user` and set the user to what you want to log in as.**

Where does Ansible get `ansible.cfg`?  The same file explains:

```
# nearly all parameters can be overridden in ansible-playbook 
# or with command line flags. ansible will read ANSIBLE_CONFIG,
# ansible.cfg in the current working directory, .ansible.cfg in
# the home directory or /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg, whichever it
# finds first
```

Comment: Thanks @Deltik, would you be able to answer [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/1081619/where-to-store-variables-in-ansible) as well?

Comment: @HowardLee: Your [other question](http://superuser.com/q/1081619/83694) is primarily opinion-based and not a good fit for Super User.

Answer (score 20):

Another way is to use `--user` to define remote ssh user. Type `ansible-playbook --help` to read more. This is my typical command:

`ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yml --user <user> --ask-pass -vvvv`

`--ask-pass` will prompt to enter password for `--user`

Answer (score 16):

In addition to modifying the `ansible.cfg`, u can also define variables for 'all' group or other groups

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#group-variables

```
[all:vars]
ansible_user = root
ansible_port = 22
```